# Android, need to access an ImageView that has been dynamically created with addView()

Tags: android

Here is what I am trying to do -

[image: Slider with Title]

While there is many parts that go into this I think my problems would go away if I could only reference the dynamically created ImageViews in code below. To accomplish what is in pic I have been trying to use a HorizontalSrcollView. The code where I dynamically create ImageViews -

```
        for (int j = 1; j < cr_count + 1; j++) {
        LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list);
        comp_hsv =
                (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroller);
        ImageView i = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        i.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
        l.addView(i);
         comp_hsv.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_LEFT);
    }
```

my.XML -

```
            <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroller"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:scrollbarSize="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        </HorizontalScrollView>
```

I have been running all over the internet trying to get this to work and no luck. Any suggestions/help would be awesome.

Comment: What is it you are trying to achieve, and how exactly doesn't that work?

Comment: @Christine  The TextView is set with data from a cursor. Each circular image corresponds to a cursor data field which will be the text in  this one and only TextView.

Comment: What TextView?  Have a look at ViewPagerIndicator.

Comment: @Christine , Sorry, the TextView isn't in the posted code I was referring to the "Otay" in pic as being a TextView. Hitting the arrow will highlight the next circular image and corresponding data will be set in TextView. I am now checking out ViewPagerIndicator, thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer viewpager would as a better solution. However, in case you cant change too much of the code, you might try this inexpensive code.

```
List<ImageView> refs = new ArrayList<ImageView>();

for (int j = 1; j < cr_count + 1; j++) {
    LinearLayout l = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list);
    comp_hsv = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroller);
    ImageView i = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    i.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
    l.addView(i);

--> refs.add(i);

    comp_hsv.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_LEFT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `imageView.setId(urId)` while you create the `ImageView`. Later use `imageView.getId()` to get the id.
You can loop through your `LinearLayout` to check the id

```
for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof ImageView) {
            //check id here
        } 
    }
```